# How to make an adaptive image slider?

Tags: html, css, slider, responsive

I have a small slider on JQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <img src="2.jpg">
    <img src="3.jpg">
  </div>
  <a class="prev"></a>
  <a class="next"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
  float: right;
  max-width: 712px;
  max-height: 423px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slider div {
  position:relative;
  width: 10000px;
  height: 424px;
}
.slider div img {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 712px;
}
```

On the desktop, everything is fine, because the images are stretched in width to 712 pixels. But on mobile devices, I need the images to stretch to the width of the block with id = slider

But, the images are inside the div block with a width of 10000 pixels - they are stretched to 712 pixels. How to make sure that the images inside the div div stretch to 100% of the parent div with id = slider?

Comment: how can we reproduce your problem? any snippet?

Comment: for images can use width: cal(100vw - 0px); (some pixels need to reduce as padding or something.) using media queries is good choice for this

Comment: @YadabSd tried already, such a problem: https://prnt.sc/s528sy

Comment: @NishargShah https://jsfiddle.net/enshtein/hp9bvk47/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Corrections:

- don't use float: left in .slider
- use width in vw for small screen in media for images
- catch the

```js
window.sldrcnt = 0;
function slider(direct) {
    if (direct == 'prev') {
     if (window.sldrcnt != 0)
      window.sldrcnt = window.sldrcnt + 1;
    } else {
     if ( Math.abs(window.sldrcnt - 1) == $('.slider div img').length )
      window.sldrcnt = 0;
     else
      window.sldrcnt = window.sldrcnt - 1;
    }
 $('.slider div').animate({'marginLeft': window.sldrcnt * $('.slider div img').innerWidth()}, 600);
}
```

```css
.slider {
  /*float: right;*/
  max-width: 712px;
  max-height: 423px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slider div {
  position:relative;
  width: 10000px;
  height: 424px;
}
.slider div img {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 0px); /* instead 0 use the total space if  used both left & right  */
}
.slider .prev, .slider .next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
.slider .next {
  right: 20px;
}
.slider .prev {
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
</head>
<body>
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/712x423/a155a1/fff">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/712x423/6da155/fff">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/712x423/c93a63/fff">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" href="javascript:slider('prev');void(0);">prev</a>
  <a class="next" href="javascript:slider('next');void(0);">next</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```